# Will a 5th edition of Dungeons & Dragons be released?

Tags: dungeons-and-dragons, dnd-5e

The split between fans of Pathfinder/D&D 3.5 and Dungeons & Dragons 4E, combined with the rehiring of d20/D&D 3.0 developer Monte Cook, have caused many fans to speculate about an upcoming 5th edition of D&D. Is there any truth to this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Yes.** [The New York Times](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/01/10/arts/video-games/dungeons-dragons-remake-uses-players-input.html?_r=2&hpw) revealed on January 9, 2012 that a 5th edition of D&D was in the works for a release at Gen Con 2013. Mike Mearls [confirmed it](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/Article.aspx?x=dnd/4ll/20120109) shortly thereafter. An [open playtest for the game](http://company.wizards.com/content/dd-next-playtest-has-begun) began on May 25, 2012.